# c programming error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before '{ '

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>       
#include <math.h> 

typedef struct tagPoint

{     
double x, y; 
} point, *pPoint;  

typedef struct tagSource 
{     
point location;     
float power; 
} source, *pSource;

typedef struct

{


{
    struct tagSource tagSource[100],random [2];
        struct tagPoint};

double spl(double w, double r);
double spl_total(struct tagSource *srcs, int count, struct tagPoint dest);
double distance(struct tagPoint p1, struct tagPoint p2);
double power(double w);
int sort(struct tagSource *srcs, int count);
int display(struct tagSource *srcs, int count);


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
```

The error message reads:c:15: expected specifier-qualifier-list before '{' token

I tried to look up how to solve this but i am at a dead end. Please help me to mend this. Thanks

Comment: You should improve your code formatting. And why didn't you close the last `{` with a corresponding `}`? The same with the one at line 19.

Comment: line 15 is `} source, *pSource;` right?

Comment: Please cleanup your code before posting here, this is a complete mess.

Answer (score 0):

To say the least change:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
;{
```

to

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a semi-colon after the definition of the signature of the function. So there you just need to remove the `;` after `int main (int argc, char*argv[])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct

{


{
    struct tagSource tagSource[100],random [2];
        struct tagPoint};
```

You got two `{` here.Remove any one of them. Also,change

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
;{
```

to

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
```

After making these changes,the error will be gone!